# Command prompt not opening but executing the command in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I am new to .net, I have a task in which I need to open command prompt from a particular directory and then execute few commands in it. All this needs to be done by code. I tried the similar for testing purpose in below code

```
            var res = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\";
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("mkdir test");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
```

The problem is, it is making directory as the command says but command prompt is not opening. For the actual task the command is different in which I am starting the server. So for that the command prompt needs to open and show the details of server.

Comment: The C# [Process class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) is a C# wrapper class for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. There should be read all three Microsoft documentations carefully and completely to get knowledge how to use them correct to run one or more executables from within a C# coded program.

Comment: Further, I suggest to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help carefully and completely. There is explained how the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` interprets the argument string(s) after option `/C` (run command line and close itself) or option `/K` (run command line and keep running). I recommend to used left to option `/K` also the option `/D`. I hope, the execution of `cmd.exe` is not for just creating a directory as the example lets readers think.

Comment: By the way: There is (nearly) never the need to run `cmd.exe` from within a C# coded application as `cmd.exe` uses Windows library functions which every application coded in C# can use too. Whenever a programmer asks for help on how to run `cmd.exe` from within a C# coded application, then it is clear for me that the programmer has not done carefully enough the research before starting programming and tries to solve an [XY problem](https://xyprobleminfo/). C# code can be used to do everything required for that task without running `cmd.exe` at all.

Comment: I really hope the real problem to solve is not starting `cmd.exe` from within the C# coded application and then communicate via standard input, standard output and standard error streams with the Windows command processor. `cmd` is not designed for such process to process communication. It is designed to execute internal commands of `cmd` and executables using `CreateProces`. So if the real goal is to run multiple executables, that should be done directly in C# code using the `Process` class multiple times without the roundabout route of using `cmd.exe` controlled by the C# coded program.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is this line:

```
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

I feel like the name of that property is pretty self explanitory, but here is what the [MSDN entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-6.0) about it says:

> Property Value
> Boolean
> `true` if the process should be started without
> creating a new window to contain it; otherwise, `false`. The default is
> `false`.

Also, the line regarding shell execute is also likely to prevent a window from appearing:

```
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

I suggest you look into all the properties of `StartInfo` that you're using here because this looks like you copy pasted code without understanding it at all.

Comment: Hi, @Logarr, thanks for help, I did what you said and it worked, but now the command prompt just pop up for a second and after executing the command it turns off. I need it to close only when someone does it manually.-- 
                Process cmd = new Process();
                cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"some directory here";
                cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C some command here";
                cmd.Start();